# Is it possible to create a device file for virtual frame buffer?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, framebuffer

We are having some frame buffer devices like x server. Is it possible to create a device file for a virtual frame buffer? What ever i write image data in to that device file should appear on virtual frame buffer.